# Difference between hours when time2 small then time1 php

Tags: php, mysql

i have an app that calculates the overtime of product leaders based on the number of extra hours their employees work between two dates.
The query i have works perfectly if the time of end is bigger then the time of start, but not in the opposite.
I have the following code:

```
$query = "SELECT Y.Name_Of_ThePL, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(X.EndTime) - TIME_TO_SEC(X.StartTime))) AS SUM FROM X, Y WHERE X.ID_PL = Y.ID_PL and 
    Data >= '$datepicker' AND Data <= '$datepicker1' and Y.ID_PL = $idPL GROUP BY Y.Name_Of_ThePL";

    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while($rowcount = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $sum = $rowcount['EndTime'] - $rowcount['StartTime'];
        $count += abs($sum);
    }
```

Imagine that i have a start time of 22:00 and an end time of 06:00, in the previous method it returns 16, but in fact the real result is 8. 
How can i handle this? Any suggest!?

P.S: And yes, i'll put this working with PDO.

Appreciate your attention.

Comment: Why would the result be 8? Why not 8 % 24? It would be simpler if you stored a DATETIME in mysql

Comment: I have update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution that comes to mind (untested):

```
while($rowcount = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $et = $rowcount['EndTime']; $st = $rowcount['StartTime'];
    $sum = $et < $st ? 
          $et + (24 - $st)
          :
          $et - $st;
    $count += $sum;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
  $dtime="22:00";
 $atime="06:00";
 $nextDay=$dtime>$atime?1:0;
 $dep=EXPLODE(':',$dtime);
 $arr=EXPLODE(':',$atime);
 $diff=ABS(MKTIME($dep[0],$dep[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j'),DATE('y'))-MKTIME($arr[0],$arr[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j')+$nextDay,DATE('y')));
 $hours=FLOOR($diff/(60*60));
 $mins=FLOOR(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));
 $secs=FLOOR(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));
 IF(STRLEN($hours)<2){$hours="0".$hours;}
 IF(STRLEN($mins)<2){$mins="0".$mins;}
 IF(STRLEN($secs)<2){$secs="0".$secs;}
 echo $hours.':'.$mins.':'.$secs;
```

Output:08:00:00

Demo:https://eval.in/467530

Updated:

```
$sum=array();
while($rowcount = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $dtime=$rowcount['StartTime'];
     $atime=$rowcount['EndTime'];
     $nextDay=$dtime>$atime?1:0;
     $dep=EXPLODE(':',$dtime);
     $arr=EXPLODE(':',$atime);
     $diff=ABS(MKTIME($dep[0],$dep[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j'),DATE('y'))-MKTIME($arr[0],$arr[1],0,DATE('n'),DATE('j')+$nextDay,DATE('y')));
     $hours=FLOOR($diff/(60*60));
     $mins=FLOOR(($diff-($hours*60*60))/(60));
     $secs=FLOOR(($diff-(($hours*60*60)+($mins*60))));
     IF(STRLEN($hours)<2){$hours="0".$hours;}
     IF(STRLEN($mins)<2){$mins="0".$mins;}
     IF(STRLEN($secs)<2){$secs="0".$secs;}
     $sum[]=$hours;
}
echo array_sum($sum);
```

Output:16:00

Comment: This works in this particular case. But what if a product leader as an employee that worked extra hours from 22:00 to 06:00 and another one that worked from 06:00 to 14:00.... The overtime should be 16 hours. How can i accomplish that!?

Answer (score 1):

Using SQL Time different :

```
SELECT TIMEDIFF('2015-11-09 12:02:00','2015-11-09 10:02:00') * 24*60*60;
-- result: 1728000000.000000 the difference in seconds.


SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2015-11-09 12:02:00','2015-11-09 10:02:00'); 
-- result: -7200 the difference in seconds.
```

You can use above code to apply to hours.
FYI, these method can return minus results.

Comment: The problem on that approach is that i don't have in the database a datetime of end... i have separated fields. One for date of start, timestart and timeEnd

Comment: You can combine them into a single string using Concat function See this : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat